# django i18n does not use my .mo files

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-i18n

I'm trying to internationalize my django app but I'm stuck.

I tried to translate some strings for testing purpose and it succeed but now even if I edit the .po files and compile to create .mo files it still translate just like the first test with the first test values on the first test strings. I don't know why, i've been searching for days.

here is my settings.py middleware part :

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
)
```

the context processors part :

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

and the internationalization part :

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-gb'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOCAL_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale/'), #BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
)

LANGUAGES = (
    ('fr', _('French')),
    ('en', _('English')),
)
```

There is a 'locale' directory at the root of my project, (i've already tried to put the absolute path in my LOCAL_PATHS).

.po files are generated by "python manage.py makemessages -l en -l fr -e djhtml -e py" at 'my/project/locale/lang[en or fr]/LC_MESSAGES/django.po' and .mo files are generated by "python manage.py compilemessages" at 'my/project/locale/lang[en or fr]/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo'.

I tried to clean the cache, restart the server (the runserver thing), but it still doesn't take into account any modifications on .po files.

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `LOCALE_PATHS`, not LOCAL ([link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#locale-paths)).

Comment: @lemour_a No problem. Good luck. You need it for work with translations :)